# Cannot run active file in visual studio when connected to linux server

Tags: python, linux, visual-studio, linode

I'm currently on the steep part of the learning curve with a Linux server and running into a very frustrating issue.

Initially, I was running python scripts from the root user, then I learned that this was bad and created a new user and am working on migrating everything over to this new user. For some reason, when I set up the new user in exactly the same way that I set up the root I can no longer run the active file. From the root user, I can either click 'run active file' or the small play button in the top right corner but that disappears when I log in as the new user.

I receive the error message '''only files on disk can be run in the terminal'''

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong? Like I said still learning this stuff so if any more detail is needed please let me know.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Well this was dumb, the Python extension was installed when running the root but had to separately install the extension for the additional user. Fixed the issue.